# Edit UITextField Font Size with UIStepper

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, font-size, uistepper

Is there a way to edit a UITextField's font size with a UIStepper? i.e, tap the add button and the UITextField's font size increases by 1 or 5? So far I have tried `[textField adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:value];` with no luck. How could I do this? Also, if I can't control the font size with a UIStepper, how else can I edit the font size? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be using:

```
[textField setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:value]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIFont *textFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:8.0];
[textField setFont:textFont];
```

Try This...

Comment: This has nothing to do with using the UISteppers value for the font size.